# How to do retrofti calls with OOP?

Tags: java, android, oop, retrofit

Today i was working on my homework, which it was making simple apps with retrofit calls and learning new things for code improvement, and somehow i saw there are so many ways to write less code and do better with OOP. So to improve my code experiment I'm trying to do my retrofit calls with OOP. So this is my issue right now:

Consider a simple retrofit call with `CompositeDisposable`( I'm developing my simples with MVP )  :

```
    mView.showProgress(1);
    RequestRemainingProductsRequest requestRemainingProductsRequest = new RequestRemainingProductsRequest();
    requestRemainingProductsRequest.distributorId = distributorId;
    requestRemainingProductsRequest.requestCode = requestCode;
    requestRemainingProductsRequest.requestType = 1;

    NetworkCalls.getObservableList();

    compositeDisposable.add(getApi().requestRemainingProducts(requestRemainingProductsRequest)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Products>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<Products> products) throws Throwable {
                mView.hideProgress(1);
                mView.getRemainingProducts(products);
            }
        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                mView.hideProgress(1);
                mView.showLog(throwable.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }));
```

And, Another retrofit call without `CompositeDisposable` :

```
    ProductSellerRequest productSellerRequest = new ProductSellerRequest();
    productSellerRequest.centralId = centralsList.get(i).requestCentralId;
    productSellerRequest.requestType = 0;
    productSellerRequest.productId = Constant.currentProduct.productId;
    getApi().checkProductExistInRequest(productSellerRequest)
            .enqueue(new Callback<ProductSellerCallback>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ProductSellerCallback> call, Response<ProductSellerCallback> response) {

                    hideProgress(myViewHolder);
                    showAddDialog(myViewHolder, v, response, i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ProductSellerCallback> call, Throwable t) {

                    hideProgress(myViewHolder);
                }
            });
```

So let's say I created a java class with `NetworkCalls.java`, and created 2 voids like this:

```
public static void getObservableList()
{

}

public static void getWithoutObservableList()
{

}
```

How to handle my response to return to my `Presenter/Activity`?

This is how i using `StringBuilder` and returning my String, but I'm trying do similiar way to make repository for my Network Calls, then learn all all i should know about `Repository Pattern`.

```
public static String TotalPriceStringBuilder(int Price){
    String DecimalPrice = String.format("%,d", Price);

    String FinalString = new StringBuilder("Price : ").append(DecimalPrice).append(" $").toString();
    return String.valueOf(FinalString);
}
```

This is what I've tried, but i still don't know how to fix it or make it work, what to return, and how to return and etc... :

```
private static ApiClient mApi;

private List<Products> receivedProducts;
private int hideProgress;
private boolean status;
private String message;

public void getObservableList(RequestRemainingProductsRequest requestRemainingProductsRequest, CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable)
{
    compositeDisposable.add(getApi().requestRemainingProducts(requestRemainingProductsRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Products>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(List<Products> products) throws Throwable {
                    hideProgress = 1;
                    receivedProducts = products;
                    status = TRUE;
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    hideProgress = 1;
                    status = FALSE;
                    message = throwable.getMessage().toString();
                }
            }));

    if (status == TRUE) {
        return hideProgress, receivedProducts, status;
    } else {
        return hideProgress, message, status;
    }
}


public ApiClient getApi() {
    if (mApi == null) {
        mApi = ApiService.getClient().create(ApiClient.class);
    }
    return mApi;
}
```

If i use `static` method I'll get bunch of errors like can't be refrenced from a static context or etc...